# is it possible to set $(this) in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I want to set `#first` and `#second` as $(this) to use element id only when function is calling.
is it possible?or any other way?

```
 (function( $ ){
        $.fn.showCircle = function(top,right) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $(this).css({
                    right:right,
                    top:top,
                });
            });

        };
    })( jQuery );
    $('#first').showCircle(300,200);
    $('#second').showCircle(800,200);
```

Comment: you can't *set* `this`

Comment: i think the `this` inside `timeout` would point to `window` and not to your respective element. Try assigning `var self = this;` before `timeout` and them use `self` inplace of `this` inside `timeout` and it should work.

Comment: when I log(this) output is window 
what is reference of this?
is there any other way not to use id in function?
@JaromandaX

Comment: no idea what it is you're trying to achieve, hence why I made the comment that you can't *set* `this` ... however, you can call a function in a way to make `this` in that function what you want - again, no idea what you're trying to achieve with your code, so I can't really help further

Comment: yes it pointing to window let me test @Panther

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to set css to elements with different element and call functions like this 
    $('#first').showCircle(300,200);
    $('#second').showCircle(300,200);
...
@JaromandaX

Comment: @Panther It worked thank u :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @panther comment inside `$timeout` this refer to `window` so as @panther said I changed the function :

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.showCircle = function (top, right) {
            var self = this;
            $timeout(function () {
                $(self.selector).css({
                    right: right,
                    top: top,
                });
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jQuery.proxy()` to set `this` at a function call

```
$timeout($.proxy(function () {
            $(this).css({
                right:right,
                top:top,
            });
        }, this));
```